# Relational Algebra Highest Duration

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

i was wondering if it was possible to calculate the duration in relation algebra, having two attributes "time_start" and "time_end", my objective would be finding the tuple with the highest duration (which in my mind can't be done without doing the time_end-time_start to find the duration and so checking which is the highest).

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Upvoted to neutralize.

Answer (score 0):

Relational algebra isn't concerned with how attribute values are calculated, such calculations are considered to be part of a separate domain algebra.  I agree that you need to compute the duration and can't just compare start and end times, so you can either extend your relation with a duration attribute, or define a new relation `durations (time_start PK, time_end PK, duration)` with which to join.

The second part of your question is more interesting from the relational algebra point of view.  RA doesn't have `ORDER BY` or `TOP` / `LIMIT`.  A self join on a.duration < b.duration (theta join) followed by an antijoin (left outer join where right-hand side is null) should give us the expected result.  How this works is the theta join finds all the ordered pairs of durations, and the highest duration won't be found in the first/lesser position.  Antijoining the original relation with the result of the theta join allows us to eliminate all but the tuple with the highest duration.